# Umbraco is doing something with querystring, it never makes it to asp.net controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco

```
Umbraco: ver: 4.8
```

The page in Umbraco is setup with the `link:   mycontroller-myaction`

I have no problem with this routing the controller/action in question.  We're using the Node Factory to get the current node (umbraco.NodeFactory.Node.GetCurrent().Id) which is populated on the view (Razor).  However, if I have my action setup to accept a parameter:

```
 public ViewResult MyAction(int id) {  }
```

Going to `www.domain.com/mycontroller-myaction?id=1234`

the querystring on EITHER the `umbraco.library.RequestQueryString` or the base Request object on ControllerBase does not contain the "id" querystring.

So to me, Umbraco is doing something with it and I don't see what.  I don't know enough about Umbraco to know what I need to do, for Umbraco's route handling to ensure it passes on the querystring.

Anyone able to provide some insight?

**Note:**  Circumventing Umbraco by not going to the route specified in Umbraco for the page as listed above, and instead going to `domain.com/mycontroller/myaction?id=1234` works fine - more reason to know I don't know enough about what Umbraco is doing with querystrings.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with url rewriting:

[Url rewriting .NET](http://www.urlrewriting.net/116/de/home.html)

Look at the docs, in page 10 and following.

Comment: And your saying that umbraco is using this library?

Comment: Yes, Umbraco uses this library. Although it depends on the configuration. Look at config/UrlRewriting.config to see if you have some rewriting rule enabled. Apart from this rules, it can be doing something with the query strings (see the manual).